# Tornado request timeouts

Tags: python, tornado

I have a Tornado Web application which connects to an external app server on a TCP port on localhost. Sometimes, if the app server responds slowly, then even requests to the Tornado server which do not talk to the app server become slow as they are held up for the other requests to finish. What's the right way to handle this?

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: Can you show some of the code in which you connect to your app server over TCP? I'm concerned you're using a blocking-style connection, which would explain why Tornado can't respond to other requests while it waits for your app server.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in such scenarios is start a new Thread on each request(in handlers that may take longer than 500 ms). For this, you need to declare your method (e.g get) as asynchronous using @asynchronous decorator. [See here for more details.](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=asynchronous#tornado.web.asynchronous)

Once you declare a request handler method as asynchronous, you have to call self.finish() yourself. Otherwise tornado would call it itself after the method is executed. See [async networking](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/networking.html)

The following is a code snippet that starts a Thread and let it handle the request...

```
class MainRequestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
        def post(self):
        MainRequestThread(self).start()

class MainRequestThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, request = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainRequestThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

    def run(self):
        #Do some long processing here...
        self.request.finish("Some cool message") # self.request has the self of RequestHandler here
```

Note: Avoid using the same structure on every request handler. Creating Threads has overhead too.

Comment: Be careful when using threads.  In particular, you must use `IOLoop.add_callback` to transfer control back to the event loop's thread before calling `request.finish`: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#thread-safety-notes  The recommended way to use threads from Tornado is with coroutines and a concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.